# How do I start a local Joomla! User Group?

Tags: joomla-user-groups

I spend a lot of time in South Florida (Ft. Lauderdale, Miami and the Florida Keys).

There are no Joomla! User Groups here (yet), and I think Miami and the surrounding areas really need one.

How do I start a local Joomla! User Group?

Answer (score 6):

This page might help. It outlines the requirements:

http://community.joomla.org/user-group-faqs.html

This may also help, though the audio is pretty bad:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QbFhjPIzQoY

Comment: Could you maybe add the summary to your answer?